# AsyncTask and Looper.prepare() crash on every 6th call

Tags: android, android-asynctask, looper

i have an issue with looper.prepare() in doInBackground(). if i donot use looper.prepare it generates an exception "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" and when i use looper.prepare it works fine for 5 calls to looper.prepare and on sixth call it generates following exception.

```
08-15 11:29:48.078: W/System.err(14133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:74)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at the.bike.washer.SelectLocation$setUserCurrentLocation.doInBackground(SelectLocation.java:1504)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at the.bike.washer.SelectLocation$setUserCurrentLocation.doInBackground(SelectLocation.java:1)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-15 11:29:48.088: W/System.err(14133):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Here is the code

```
try {
                Looper.prepare();
                locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                    double lat = 48.8742;
                    double lng = 2.3470;
                    Constants.coordinates = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    Constants.address = getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                    result = "no gps";
                } else {
                    //this.canGetLocation = true;
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, SelectLocation.this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                Constants.coordinates = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                Constants.address = getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, SelectLocation.this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                    Constants.coordinates = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                    Constants.address = getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: `AsyncTask` uses a thread pool to run the background work. The looper is attached to the thread. When you get the same thread again the exception is raised.

Comment: Then how can i avoid this?

Comment: It is not a good idea to have a handler in an AsyncTask. I am afraid you have to use a different design.

Comment: Forget about handlers, forget about loopers, just let it be to execute the damn code. AsyncTask has it's own handling mechanism. Let it be. It is actually extremely simple and very useful class, props to Google for making it, and stop messing with it. OR manage a custom thread that you create.

Comment: Using asyncTask it generates exception on every first execution as i have mentioned in question. So should i have to forget asyntask and use separate thread or is there any workaround with asynctask to solve this issue. Please suggest me simple way. thanks

Comment: i have also tried Looper.myLooper().quit() but it seems it not working. No success

Comment: @user1722206 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/j9C4bx3TELg check Dianne hackborn suggestion. To quote " AsyncTask and Looper are two fundamentally different threading models, which are not compatible.  If you want a thread running a looper, use HandlerThread".http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Comment: Okay, use Async if the task it executes is a short time execution, ie maybe 0-5 seconds. If you want something to be running in the background for a while, ex. lifetime of the activity, then you would use something else. This page contains THE perfect documentation for AsyncTask, if you follow it and still are getting an error, then let me know: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: ok thankyou.. i'll inform you :)

Comment: Why do you want to call Looper.prepare() in doInBackground? To init a handler?

Comment: if i do not call Looper.prepare(). i get following exception
"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: @user1722206 You are not showing your Async code, and considering the issue is with that code, it is pretty reckless to not put it in your question. Show your code, the full Async code and where you are executing the Async function in the Activity. Also, this link has the full guide on Async with very good details, in case you didn't see it before: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i showed you my doInBackground code above. thank you for help. The issue is solved. just need to call locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, SelectLocation.this); outside of AsynTask. Thank you every one